# Release Google Places Autocomplete Response - now declared as internal

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Recently upgrading Google API versions from 11.8.0 to 12.0.1 resulted in `task.result.release()` in my completion listener from `Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse>` being marked as internal.

Should I handle the possibility of an internal data leak differently? Does the Google Places API now handle releasing the result itself? I cannot find information about this in the [release notes for 12.0.0 or 12.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_20_2018_-_version_1200). The current documentation still says [you must release the result](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse).

Here is where I use it:

```
.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {

        {...}

        //Release to avoid internal data leak
        task.result.release()
    } else {
        Log.e("AutoCompletePredictions", task.exception?.message)

        //Release to avoid internal data leak
        task.result.release()
    }
}
.addOnFailureListener(this@NewLocationActivity) {
    Log.e("AutoCompletePredictions", it.message)
}
```

This is the error message I am receiving:

> zzb.release is marked as internal and should not be accessed from apps less... (⌘F1) 
>   This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.  Examples of API restrictions: * Method can only be invoked by a subclass * Method can only be accessed from within the same library (defined by the Gradle library group id) .* Method can only be accessed from tests. . You can add your own API restrictions with the @RestrictTo annotation.

The full `getSuggestions()` method in which I use the completion listener

```
private fun getSuggestions() {
    val filter = AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
        .setCountry(CountryManager.getCountryISO())
        .build()

    Places.getGeoDataClient(this@NewLocationActivity/*, null*/) // uncomment for v11.8.0
        .getAutocompletePredictions(
            activity_new_location_edit_text.text.toString(),
            null,
            filter
        )
        .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val addressList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

                var index = 0
                for(item in task.result) {
                    if(index >= MAX_SUGGESTION_RESULTS)
                        break

                    addressList.add(item.getFullText(null).toString())
                    index++
                }

                if(!(addressList.size == 1 && addressList[0] == activity_new_location_edit_text.text.toString()))
                    loadGoogleAddressesIntoSuggestionList(addressList)

                //Release to avoid internal data leak
                task.result.release()
            } else {
                Log.e("AutoCompletePredictions", task.exception?.message)

                //Release to avoid internal data leak
                task.result.release()
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this@NewLocationActivity) {
            Log.e("AutoCompletePredictions", it.message)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an unintended change.

It started in 12.0.0, that has the following "known issue" in its [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_20_2018_-_version_1200):

> An annotation causes spurious lint errors claiming `GoogleSignIn` and
>   `CredentialsClient` are internal-only. These can safely be ignored.

Guess they weren't only for `GoogleSignIn` and `CredentialsClient`, but they fixed only those in [12.0.1](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_version_1201):

> Fixes issue that caused spurious Android lint errors claiming
>   `GoogleSignIn` and `CredentialsClient` were internal-only.

The corresponding source code of `release()` appears to be the same across versions 11.8.0-12.0.1, so i believe you can safely ignore these warnings.

Comment: I opened an issue tracker based on your answer. Anyone interested can find it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77840257